# HQL/JPQL Self left join

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, join, self

I have a Friendship table that looks like this

```
friend_of/friend_to
1            2    
2            1
1            3
```

Basically, friendship are bidirectional so when i have a pair AB and BA that mean the friendship exist. But if (like in this example) a pair is missing this means user 3 has a pending friend request.

I can easily select a pending friend like this in SQL:

```
SELECT f1.friend_of 
FROM friends f1 
LEFT JOIN friendship
f2 ON f1.friend_of = f2.friend_to 
AND f1.friend_to = f2.friend_of 
WHERE f2.friend_of IS NULL AND f1.friend_to=3;
```

I would need help to translate this into a HQL query (hl because it has the JOIN WITH feature..). How can I achieve this self join?

Thank you !